# how to validate multiple toaster messages in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using Chrome browser(Version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)). There are two different operations happening in my application webpage. The success toaster for the result of first operation and second operation does not come simultaneously. There is a delay between the appearance of both toasters. I see that the second toaster appears after the first toaster has disappeared ( I have set timeout to 3 seconds). How would I validate using protractor that both toasters have appeared. The messages inside toasters are different. The ID of the toasters are same.

All the answers which I have seen here in stackoverflow site, doesn't work for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

First validate the appearance of first toaster, because the second appears when first disappears use waiting :

```
 browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element(by.id("toaster1"))), 30000).then(function () {

 {here place the code for validation of second toaster}
})
```

Comment: `browser.findElement(by.css(".toast-message")).then(function(element){
          element.getText().then(function(text){
            console.log("Text got "+text);
                expect(toast1).toEqual(text.toString());
          });
        });
`
@sanja-  I am using the above code to validate my toaster but I see that this code is always fetching the content of second toaster and hence my validation of message of toast1 is failing.

Comment: before all put the validation of the toaster1. And You will have all

Comment: can u please provide a sample code?
I am not able to fetch the value of toast1. It is always fetching toast2.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var toast1 = element(by.css(".toast-message")); 
   expect(toast1).toEqual("validateText");
   browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element(by.id("toaster1"))), 30000).then(function () {
     var toast2 = element(by.css(".toast-message2")); 
     expect(toast2).toEqual("validateText2");
```

})